# Converting ListActivity to ListFragment

Tags: android, fragment, listactivity, android-listfragment

How can I go about changing this ListActivity to a ListFragment..? I have looked on the web for some resources that would help and have tried myself but to no avail. Does ListFragment have same methods as ListActivity..? Please help. Thank you all in advance.

Here is my Code:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.hb.examples.pinnedsection.R;
import com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView;
import com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter;

public class SectionedListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    static class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements PinnedSectionListAdapter {

        private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
            R.color.green_light, R.color.orange_light,
            R.color.blue_light, R.color.red_light };

        public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);

            final int sectionsNumber = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
            prepareSections(sectionsNumber);

            int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;
            for (char i=0; i<sectionsNumber; i++) {
                Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, String.valueOf((char)('A' + i)));
                section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                section.listPosition = listPosition++;
                onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
                add(section);

                final int itemsNumber = (int) Math.abs((Math.cos(2f*Math.PI/3f * sectionsNumber / (i+1f)) * 25f));
                for (int j=0;j<itemsNumber;j++) {
                    Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, section.text.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + " - " + j);
                    item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                    item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                    add(item);
                }

                sectionPosition++;
            }
        }

        protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) { }
        protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) { }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            view.setTag("" + position);
            Item item = getItem(position);
            if (item.type == Item.SECTION) {
                //view.setOnClickListener(SectionedListActivity.this);
                view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[item.sectionPosition % COLORS.length]));
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).type;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
            return viewType == Item.SECTION;
        }

    }

    static class FastScrollAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

        private Item[] sections;

        public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) {
            sections = new Item[sectionsNumber];
        }

        @Override protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) {
            sections[sectionPosition] = section;
        }

        @Override public Item[] getSections() {
            return sections;
        }

        @Override public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            if (section >= sections.length) {
                section = sections.length - 1;
            }
            return sections[section].listPosition;
        }

        @Override public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            if (position >= getCount()) {
                position = getCount() - 1;
            }
            return getItem(position).sectionPosition;
        }

    }

    static class Item {

        public static final int ITEM = 0;
        public static final int SECTION = 1;

        public final int type;
        public final String text;

        public int sectionPosition;
        public int listPosition;

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return text;
        }

    }

    private boolean hasHeaderAndFooter;
    private boolean isFastScroll;
    private boolean addPadding;
    private boolean isShadowVisible = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            isFastScroll = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFastScroll");
            addPadding = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("addPadding");
            isShadowVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isShadowVisible");
            hasHeaderAndFooter = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter");
        }
        initializeHeaderAndFooter();
        initializeAdapter();
        initializePadding();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("isFastScroll", isFastScroll);
        outState.putBoolean("addPadding", addPadding);
        outState.putBoolean("isShadowVisible", isShadowVisible);
        outState.putBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter", hasHeaderAndFooter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (item != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        menu.getItem(0).setChecked(isFastScroll);
        menu.getItem(1).setChecked(addPadding);
        menu.getItem(2).setChecked(isShadowVisible);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_fastscroll:
                isFastScroll = !isFastScroll;
                item.setChecked(isFastScroll);
                initializeAdapter();
                break;
            case R.id.action_addpadding:
                addPadding = !addPadding;
                item.setChecked(addPadding);
                initializePadding();
                break;
            case R.id.action_showShadow:
                isShadowVisible = !isShadowVisible;
                item.setChecked(isShadowVisible);
                ((PinnedSectionListView)getListView()).setShadowVisible(isShadowVisible);
                break;
            case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
                hasHeaderAndFooter = !hasHeaderAndFooter;
                item.setChecked(hasHeaderAndFooter);
                initializeHeaderAndFooter();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initializePadding() {
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int padding = addPadding ? (int) (16 * density) : 0;
        getListView().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    }

    private void initializeHeaderAndFooter() {
        setListAdapter(null);
        if (hasHeaderAndFooter) {
            ListView list = getListView();

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            TextView header1 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            header1.setText("First header");
            list.addHeaderView(header1);

            TextView header2 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            header2.setText("Second header");
            list.addHeaderView(header2);

            TextView footer = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            footer.setText("Single footer");
            list.addFooterView(footer);
        }
        initializeAdapter();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initializeAdapter() {
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(isFastScroll);
        if (isFastScroll) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                getListView().setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
            }
            setListAdapter(new FastScrollAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
        } else {
            setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I was able to find a way to convert to ListFragment

Code:

```
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class PinnedListView extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {
        private boolean hasHeaderAndFooter;
        private boolean isFastScroll;
        private boolean addPadding;
        private boolean isShadowVisible = true;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view,container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                isFastScroll = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFastScroll");
                addPadding = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("addPadding");
                isShadowVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isShadowVisible");
                hasHeaderAndFooter = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter");
            }
            initializeHeaderAndFooter();
            initializeAdapter();
            initializePadding();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putBoolean("isFastScroll", isFastScroll);
            outState.putBoolean("addPadding", addPadding);
            outState.putBoolean("isShadowVisible", isShadowVisible);
            outState.putBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter", hasHeaderAndFooter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
            if (item != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            menu.getItem(0).setChecked(isFastScroll);
            menu.getItem(1).setChecked(addPadding);
            menu.getItem(2).setChecked(isShadowVisible);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_fastscroll:
                    isFastScroll = !isFastScroll;
                    item.setChecked(isFastScroll);
                    initializeAdapter();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_addpadding:
                    addPadding = !addPadding;
                    item.setChecked(addPadding);
                    initializePadding();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_showShadow:
                    isShadowVisible = !isShadowVisible;
                    item.setChecked(isShadowVisible);
                    ((PinnedSectionListView)getListView()).setShadowVisible(isShadowVisible);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
                    hasHeaderAndFooter = !hasHeaderAndFooter;
                    item.setChecked(hasHeaderAndFooter);
                    initializeHeaderAndFooter();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private void initializePadding() {
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int padding = addPadding ? (int) (16 * density) : 0;
            getListView().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        }

        private void initializeHeaderAndFooter() {
            setListAdapter(null);
            if (hasHeaderAndFooter) {
                ListView list = getListView();

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                TextView header1 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                header1.setText("First header");
                list.addHeaderView(header1);

                TextView header2 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                header2.setText("Second header");
                list.addHeaderView(header2);

                TextView footer = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
                footer.setText("Single footer");
                list.addFooterView(footer);
            }
            initializeAdapter();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initializeAdapter() {
            getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(isFastScroll);
            if (isFastScroll) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    getListView().setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
                }
                setListAdapter(new FastScrollAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
            } else {
                setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`ListFragment` will provide you with all what you need like `ListActivity`. You need to make a new Activity (Main Activity) extends FragmentActivity and make the ListFragment as a different class then add the Fragment to the Activity. If you don't know how to do this I strongly recommend you read [The Fragments Tutorial Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).